# What is the best way to store multiple selections from drop down list to database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, serialization, multi-select

I have a multi select drop down list. I:
[image]

I'm just wondering which is the best way to store it into MySQL database:
 1) *serialise()* method of PHP or 2) in specific format with different symbols like comma (,)  vertical bar (|) and etc.

For example, I have *cities* table. It contains *city_id* and *city_name*. 
One person may travel to more than one city. So he will select multiple cities. I want to store this selection somehow so that I can use them whenever I need by mysql joins.

I use Laravel 5.

Comment: or 3) use a table to store each entry with a foreign key

Comment: How about using bits combination?

Comment: That could make for really difficult queries and database optimization down the line. Stick to 3NF for sql databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way that will store your data in a normalized way is to have a separate table for the selected cities.

I don't know what entitity your selections are connected to, but say it's users.

users table

```
id   int
name string
```

etc.

userCities table:

```
id       int
userId   int
cityId   int
```

cities

```
id       int
name     string
```

So if a user selects three cities, he or she will have one row in the users table and three rows in the userCities. Doing this will enable you to create much better and faster queries than if you store the selections as a concatenated value in one column in the users table. To retrieve a user and its cities you do an outer join with userCities and cities (so that users without cities are also returned).

Comment: Id appears to be redundant in userCities

Comment: From a normalization perspective - yes. I think it's just in my fingers to put a single-column primary key on every table (old habits from bad versions of MS SQL Server ;-) )

Comment: Thank you @AndersBornholm, I think I will use this way.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have 3 tables :

- Cities (id, name)
- Users (id, name)
- City_user (id, id_city, id_user)

For example your user (1, Sakuto) has traveled to (1, Belgium) and (2, France), your table city_user will contain:

- (1, 1, 1) (User 1 has traveled to city 1)
- (2, 2, 1) (User 1 has traveled to city 2)

Comment: Id appears to be redundant in city_user

Comment: To be fully honest, I never really learned in class how to properly use primary key, so I'm always adding one. But you're probably right, they could be both primary key

Comment: Haha, same as my answer :-). I've had bad practical experiences with database engines not performing as well if you don't have a single-column primary key (even if you put indices on the other columns).